# Is there anyway to add images/pictures to barcharts in Plotly?

Tags: python, visualization, plotly-python

I'm using the raceplotly library and was curious if along my bar charts i can also add an image for each category? Has anyone done this before? something like the below picture:
[image]

I tried this in python to get the animation going but don't know how to add the image.

```
my_raceplot = barplot(data,
                      item_column='CONCEPT_NAME',
                      value_column='MATCH_COUNT',
                      time_column='WEEK')

my_raceplot.plot(title = 'Top 10 GAMES BY MP MATCH COUNT',
                 item_label = 'Top 10 GAME',
                 value_label = 'MP MATCH COUNT',
                 frame_duration = 800)
```

Comment: Here is a great answer, please refer to it. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68365990/plotly-how-to-plot-multiple-images-on-a-plotly-figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68365990/plotly-how-to-plot-multiple-images-on-a-plotly-figure) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70053158/how-to-add-images-instead-of-dots-in-a-plotly-scatter-plot-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70053158/how-to-add-images-instead-of-dots-in-a-plotly-scatter-plot-python)